# Can the null and alternative hypotheses be percentages?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, percentage

Say you've been asked to discover if data supports the assertion that more than 50% of participants in a study did whatever the study is trying to find. In determining the null and alternative hypotheses, is it necessary to convert the percentage into a number by multiplying it by the sample size (e.g., were the sample 300 people, $H_0 \leqslant 150$ and $H_A > 150$), just better practice to do so, or equally acceptable to have $H_0 \leqslant 50\%$ and $H_A > 50\%$? I know this is somewhat abstractly drawn, but I'm just as interested in the theoretical reasoning behind the answer as I am an answer in general.

Comment: This is certainly done when testing that a binomial test of a proportion but you wouldn't multiply by the sample size.  The sample size is reflected in the variance of the parameter estimate.

Comment: Since hypotheses concern assumptions, not data, how could a hypothesis possibly be framed in terms of a sample?  In your initial example the question about the proportion of participants in a study is simply answered by computing that proportion: either it exceeds 50% or it does not.  That doesn't need a hypothesis test.